# python creación de archivo txt a partir de excel

Tags: python, excel

soy nueva en python y estuve preparando un script, pero no estoy logrando el resultado, por eso vengo a pedir  apoyo de la comunidad.

Necesito necesito automatizar la lectura de un archivo excel:
[image: Excel de entrada]

Recorrer sus filas que contienen diferentes tablas y sus atributos para retornar un archivo txt con un create statement por cada tabla y la PK, cómo se ve en la imagen:

[image: archivo de salida]

Lo que hice fue traer el excel y llevarlo a un df para recorrer sus filas y luego crear el archivo de salida, sin embargo no logro dar con el código correcto para separar cada Create statement por tabla y con el formato esperado.

```
    outputFile = open('readme.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(kyd_tms)):
    outputFile.write('CREATE TABLE K2_' + kyd_tms.iloc[i,2] + ' ( ' +  
           kyd_tms.iloc[i,4] + ' ' + kyd_tms.iloc[i,8] + ' ' + kyd_tms.iloc[i,9]+ ' ' + 'PRIMARY KEY: ()); ' + '\n' )
```

cualquier ayuda me sirve mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, recuerda que usar bucles for en objetos de Pandas debe de ser tu ultimo recurso, ya que las funciones de Pandas (hechas en C) son más rapidas que los bucles for. Pero en este caso, llegamos al punto en el cual no nos queda de otra que usarlos.

Esto no responde la pregunta con exactitud, pero hice un Dataframe con algunas de las columnas del excel basado en la imagen y logré algo igual a la imagen de ejemplo.

1. Agrupamos el Dataframe por la columna que contiene el nombre de la tabla usando groupby.
2. Recorremos cada grupo. Esto se puede desempaquetar en dos variables: una será el nombre de la tabla y otra serán las columnas correspondientes a cada tabla.
3. Creamos el create table y creamos una comprensión de generador que formateé cada columna recorriendo el grupo. Entonces, colocamos saltos de lineas en cada item.
4. Usamos un principio similar al paso anterior para agregar solo las filas donde is_pk es "yes" y que estén separadas por coma.
5. Cerramos el parentesis, colocamos en punto y coma final, hacemos un par de saltos de linea, y repetimos!

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["tabla1", "col1", "int", "yes", "not null"],
                   ["tabla1", "col2", "varchar", "no", "null"],
                   ["tabla2", "a", "varchar", "yes", "null"],
                   ["tabla2", "b", "varchar", "yes", "null"],
                   ["tabla2", "c", "real", "yes", "null"]],
                  columns=["table", "field", "type", "is_pk", "is_null"])

indent = " "*8

with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    for table, group in df.groupby("table"):
        file.write("CREATE TABLE {} (\n".format(table))
        file.write("\n".join("{indent}{field} {type} {is_null},".format(indent=indent,
                                                                        field=row.field,
                                                                        type=row.type,
                                                                        is_null=row.is_null)
                             for row in group.itertuples()))
        file.write("\n{}PRIMARY KEY ({})\n".format(indent, ",".join(row.field for row in group.itertuples() if(row.is_pk == "yes"))))
        file.write(");\n\n")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución, buenísimo tip, no tenia tan clara la diferencia de procesamiento de las funciones de pandas sobre los ciclos,  en esencia es lo buscaba!

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido la respuesta c: Si queres podes apoyarme aceptandola nwn

Comment: soy nueva en esta página también, si me orientas a qué te refieres con nwm, obvio que si apoyo!

Comment: Jjajajajajaj, es un emoji de texto nomás. En realidad, no se si lo uso de forma correcta. Generalmente lo uso cuando quiero demostrar amabilidad c: (c: es una sonrisa).

Comment: jajaj bcn c: c: